# Blender Donut - Sprinkle clipping through Icing

Tags: blend-files, geometry-nodes

I am Following Blender Guru's new " **blender 3.0**" Donut tutorial and on [*Episode 9*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WAxMI1QJMQ&t=1348s), I have followed everything but IDK where I am Missing because **My sprinkles are clipping through the icing**. Anyone can please check my blend file and tell me what I am doing wrong.

[**Rendered Image**](https://ibb.co/9s0skc4)

[**Blend File**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1q40Jql5alXfcPUI3U-NT54ukfh8DC_JA?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer pretty easy, look at your sprinkles:
[image]

Do you see that -14.8 value in your X rotation? That's what is causing your issue... Select all of the sprinkles, press Ctrl+A and select **Rotation**

[image]

and your problem is fixed

[image]

Btw clipping is pretty normal in particles, you can even see that sprinkles are clipping through each other

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP, IT WORKED

Comment: Please also explain _why_ - "Select all of the sprinkles, press Ctrl+A and select Rotation" is necessary

Comment: that is explained in tens or hundreds of similar questions that had forgot to apply scale/location or rotation and I answered exactly for his specific problem..., easy answer, it works with original rotation before you apply rotation, after you apply it, it works with applied rotation