# My sprinkles are inside the donut, and sort of clipping through

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I am doing the Blender Guru tutorial and am only on part 10. The sprinkles clipping through the icing, and being on the other side of the icing as well really bugs me. I have looked up other tutorials, or looked at solutions for similar problems, but nothing has helped. I tried to work around it and make it sort of a fantasy donut by adding like spiky sprinkles, but that was worse.
I don't know how to put files into here either, if I could get help on that too please.

This is the file, if anyone can tell what is the problem.

[image]

Comment: Make sure to raise the object(s) you're using as your sprinkles (not the particles, but the instanced object) so that their origins are at the "bottom" (select the whole thing in edit mode and raise it on the Z axis until the origin (little orange dot) is at the very "bottom" of the object).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245912/blender-donut-sprinkle-clipping-through-icing You can share your file by going to https://blend-exchange.com/ and following the instructions there.